# Inheriting from a template class in c++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Let's say we have a template class `Area`, which has a member variable `T area`, a `T getArea()` and a `void setArea(T)` member functions.

I can create an `Area` object of a specific type by typing `Area<int>`.

Now I have a class `Rectangle` that inherits the `Area` class. Since `Rectangle` itself is not a template, I cannot type `Rectangle<int>`.

How do I specialize the inherited `Area` type for `Rectangle` objects?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to clarify - my questions is whether it is possible to inherit Area without specializing it, so it is not inherited as Area of ints but as Area Rectangle can specialize the types for.

Comment: It's _class template_, because it's a template from which classes are generated.

Comment: @sbi I don't intend to start a flame war here, but if Bjarne Stroustrup doesn't draw a distinction between _class template_ and _template class_ (see _The C++ Programming Language_, 4th ed., section 23.2.1), then you shouldn't either.

Comment: @MichaelWarner I seem to remember him making the distinction. That was in the 90s, though, on Usenet. Maybe he has given up since. (Or maybe he refers to an instantiated class template as a template class?)

Answer (score 326, accepted):

For understanding templates, it's of huge advantage to get the terminology straight because the way you speak about them determines the way to think about them.

Specifically, `Area` is not a template class, but a class template. That is, it is a template from which classes can be generated. `Area<int>` is such a class (it's *not* an object, but of course you can create an object from that class in the same ways you can create objects from any other class). Another such class would be `Area<char>`. Note that those are completely different classes, which have nothing in common except for the fact that they were generated from the same class template.

Since `Area` is not a class, you cannot derive the class `Rectangle` from it. You only can derive a class from another class (or several of them). Since `Area<int>` is a class, you could, for example, derive `Rectangle` from it:

```
class Rectangle:
  public Area<int>
{
  // ...
};
```

Since `Area<int>` and `Area<char>` are different classes, you can even derive from both at the same time (however when accessing members of them, you'll have to deal with ambiguities):

```
class Rectangle:
  public Area<int>,
  public Area<char>
{
  // ...
};
```

However you have to specify which classed to derive from when you define `Rectangle`. This is true no matter whether those classes are generated from a template or not. Two objects of the same class simply cannot have different inheritance hierarchies.

What you can do is to make `Rectangle` a template as well. If you write

```
template<typename T> class Rectangle:
  public Area<T>
{
  // ...
};
```

You have a template `Rectangle` from which you can get a class `Rectangle<int>` which derives from `Area<int>`, and a different class `Rectangle<char>` which derives from `Area<char>`.

It may be that you want to have a single type `Rectangle` so that you can pass all sorts of `Rectangle` to the same function (which itself doesn't need to know the Area type). Since the `Rectangle<T>` classes generated by instantiating the template `Rectangle` are formally independent of each other, it doesn't work that way. However you can make use of multiple inheritance here:

```
class Rectangle // not inheriting from any Area type
{
  // Area independent interface
};

template<typename T> class SpecificRectangle:
  public Rectangle,
  public Area<T>
{
  // Area dependent stuff
};

void foo(Rectangle&); // A function which works with generic rectangles

int main()
{
  SpecificRectangle<int> intrect;
  foo(intrect);

  SpecificRectangle<char> charrect;
  foo(charrect);
}
```

If it is important that your generic `Rectangle` is derived from a generic `Area` you can do the same trick with `Area` too:

```
class Area
{
  // generic Area interface
};

class Rectangle:
  public virtual Area // virtual because of "diamond inheritance"
{
  // generic rectangle interface
};

template<typename T> class SpecificArea:
  public virtual Area
{
  // specific implementation of Area for type T
};

template<typename T> class SpecificRectangle:
  public Rectangle, // maybe this should be virtual as well, in case the hierarchy is extended later
  public SpecificArea<T> // no virtual inheritance needed here
{
  // specific implementation of Rectangle for type T
};
```

Comment: Note: A template type parameter is part of the class of an object which instantiates that class template. In other words, it's not a component of the class, it's part of the type.

Comment: " Area is not a template class, but a class template." This is an excellent point. Because Area is not a class; therefore, we cannot  declare a pointer to the Area; Area * a_ptr. On the other hand, we can declare a pointer to an instantiated class of the template Area, Area<int> * a_ptr.

Answer (score 33):

Are you just trying to derive from `Area<int>`? In which case you do this:

```
class Rectangle : public Area<int>
{
    // ...
};
```

EDIT: Following the clarification, it seems you're actually trying to make `Rectangle` a template as well, in which case the following should work:

```
template <typename T>
class Rectangle : public Area<T>
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Finally!!! I found the solution, I was using `class Rectangle : public Area` instead of `class Rectangle : public Area<T>`

Answer (score 11):

```
class Rectangle : public Area<int> {
};
```

Answer (score 11):

Make Rectangle a template and pass the typename on to Area:

```
template <typename T>
class Rectangle : public Area<T>
{

};
```

Answer (score 7):

`Rectangle` will have to be a template, otherwise it is *just one type*. It cannot be a non-template whilst its base magically is. (Its base may be a template *instantiation*, though you seem to want to maintain the base's functionality *as a template*.)

Answer (score 7):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class t> 
class base {
protected:
    t a;
public:
    base(t aa){
        a = aa;
        cout<<"base "<<a<<endl;
    }
};

template <class t> 
class derived: public base<t>{
    public:
        derived(t a): base<t>(a) {
        }
        //Here is the method in derived class 
    void sampleMethod() {
        cout<<"In sample Method"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    derived<int> q(1);
    // calling the methods
    q.sampleMethod();
}
```

Comment: what if you had methods in the derived class? How would you define them? And most import yet, at least to me, how do you call/use those methods in your main() function?

Comment: First, this is a really old question which already has a great answer. Second, please avoid answers (and questions) which are only code. It is useful to include detailed explanations as well.