# How to inherit from Template class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Its been a while for C++, I have a class Number and several subclasses like Integer, Decimal.. I would like to override == operator to compare when two nums are numerically equal... I have something like the following, but can't seem to figure out the syntax for subclass inheriting from template class as well as syntax for overriding == operator in subclass...

```
template class <T>
class Number{
  T data;
   Number(T num) { data = num ;}
  boolean operator==(T &other){ return data == other; }
 }

class Integer : public Number{
 int iData;
 Integer(int i) { iData = i ; }
 boolean operator==(Integer &other){ return idata == other.iData; }

 }
```

Comment: This is already answere [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8810224/1032073)

Comment: `class` should be inside `<>` in the `Number` template

Comment: you also need to end your class declarations with `;`

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify a specialization, like `Number<int>`. Otherwise you cannot inherit from a template, unless your derived class is a template itself. There are some other errors in your code, like the ones mentioned in the comments, as well as the `operator==` operator, which should take `const Number<T>&` as a parameter. So in your case use e.g.

```
class Integer : public Number<int>
```

Once you do this, there is no need anymore for implementing the `operator==` in the derived class, since it will be inherited. Full working code below:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Number 
{
public:
    T data;
    Number(T num): data(num){}
    bool operator==(const Number<T> &other) { return data == other.data; }
};

class Integer : public Number<int> 
{
    using Number<int>::Number; // inherit the constructor
};

int main()
{
    Integer i1 = 10, i2 = 20;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (i1 == i2);
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89abab95a09d582f)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but I want to override the operator to do different things in subclasses.

Comment: @user1529412 You can still overload it if you don't want the behaviour in the base class, for example `bool operator==(const Integer &other) { return data == other.data; }`

Comment: Great, but the part thats confusing me ( see below), How can I subclass other things like Fraction, 
 
How would I do it for class Fraction : public Number < ?? >, fraction can have int numer, and int denom.

Comment: @user1529412 this tells you that probably `Number` is not the best base class for a `Fraction`. Maybe you shouldn't derive from `Number`, but use `Number` as members instead.

Comment: The question clearly says Integer and Fractions are Numbers...so maybe Number should be an interface.

Answer (score 2):

either

```
template<class T>
class Integer : public Number<T> {
```

or

```
class Integer : public Number<int> {
```

depending on if you want `Integer` to be a template too or not

Comment: How would I do it for class Fraction : public Number <  ?? >, also how about operator == ?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea for `Fraction` to inherit from `Number`.

Comment: Why not fraction is a number.

Comment: But `Number`, in your code-example, is not an interface, but rather an implementation, and fraction need to be implemented completely differently.

Comment: Ya, the question I am after asks for fraction and integers are numbers, I need to use display method which displays differently depending on the number class, or add method which works on all types.. Does this mean Number better be interface instead?

Comment: 'A Number Type-System' is not a good thing to write as inheritance-practise, it will only teach you bad habits. May I suggest a Text-GUI instead. But if you really want to do a number-replacement-library, then yes, I think `Number` should be an *abstract* base.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
template<class T>
class Number{
  T data;
   Number(T num) { data = num ;}
  boolean operator==(T &other){ return data == other; }
 };

template<typename T>
class Integer : public Number<T> {
 int iData;
 Integer(int i) { iData = i ; }
 boolean operator==(Integer &other){ return idata == other.iData; }

 }
```