# Override template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810224/inheriting-from-a-template-class-in-c) example on how to override a template class in C++ with a specific template, but the Visual Studio compiler keeps complaining about some sort of syntax error. This is my code:

```
enum LFOType {
    LIFO,
    FIFO
};

template<typename DataType, LFOType Behavior, int MaxElems = 10>
class LFO {
public:
    virtual DataType& top();
}

#include <string>

#include "LFO.h"

template<int MaxElems = 10>
class StringFIFO : public LFO<std::string, FIFO, MaxElems> {
public:
    virtual ~StringFIFO() {};
};
```

Now I'm trying to override the function top() in the StringFIFO-class, but I cannot get it to work. So this is what I tried:

```
template<int MaxElems = 10>
    class StringFIFO : public LFO<std::string, FIFO, MaxElems> {
    public:
        virtual ~StringFIFO() {};

        std::string top() override;
    };
```

Or instead of first overriding the declaration, just overriding it directly in the cpp-file:

```
template<int MaxElems>
std::string StringFIFO<MaxElems>::top<std::string, FIFO, MaxElems>() {

}
```

But none of these methods work. The compiler complains that `'std::basic_string<char>' is not identical or covariant to return type 'DataType&' of overridden function LFO<DataType, Behavior, MaxElems>::top`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Return type should be an lvalue reference. (`std::string&`)

Comment: Or for short: `std::string top()` != `std::string &top()`

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks! Such a stupid mistake to make! I was looking at this code for almost an hour, but I totally missed the reference ;)