# How to inherit a tamplate and accessing its parameters in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, namespaces

I am trying to inherit a template in C++. This template is using a namespace NSA, the Child Class has also a namespace called NSB.
I want to access the protected variables of the template inside a third Class. 
But I don't know how.

Those are headers:

```
NSA{
    template <typename T> class A{
    protected:
       unsigned int my_var;
    }
}

NSB{
    class B{ #Don't know how to inherit template A
    ...
    }
}
```

Inside the cpp file of class C (all header files are included)

```
using namespace NSA;
NSB{
    unsigned int x = my_var #Get an error. Unidentified
    ...
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where does `class C` come from? You're missing `namespace` before `NSA` and `NSB`.

Comment: Might be related/dup : https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/5470596

Comment: Class C is just a third class where I include the headers of Class A and Template B.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheriting from a template class in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810224/inheriting-from-a-template-class-in-c)

Comment: @YSC, use the galactic dupe hammer and close this one. That feels like exactly the right dupe.

Comment: VTC unclear as it is.

Comment: Try to edit the code in question in a way that it compiles instead of explaining what you meant in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can't derived from a template; you can only derive from a class. So `class B` has to be derived from an **instantiation** of `A`:

```
class B : public A<int> {
};
```

If you want `B` to be a template you have to say so:

```
template <class Ty>
class B : public A<Ty> {
};
```

In either case, accessing members of the base class is a bit tricker than with an ordinary class, because a template can be specialized, and members declared in the template itself might not exist in a particular specialization. So you have to say that you're talking about a member:

```
class B : public A<int> {
    unsigned f() { return A<int>::my_var; }
};
```

Here's another way to say the same thing:

```
class B : public A<int> {
    unsigned f() { return this->my_var; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Skipping the 'C' mumbo jumbo, (which you didn't explain clearly)

I believe this is what you are looking for :

```
namespace NSA{
    template <typename T> class A{
    protected:
       unsigned int my_var;
    };
}

namespace NSB{
    class B : public NSA::A<int> {
                        //  ^^^ some type or make class B as template 
    //...

    unsigned int x = my_var;
    };
}
```